# How should I structure user login and others in this website I am working on? Please see description

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, server, handlebars.js

I apologize if the question is not too clear.

As a background, I am working with ExpressJS and MongoDB (with mongoose etc). Also, I am a bit familiar with the topic, but I would like to do this the right way. I also use Handlebars as a view engine.

What I am trying to get at is, how do make it so that the server knows that a user is logged in and sends the right page, navigation bar, and other things?

I worked on a hackathon where I did something like this. Basically, it worked like this. When a user created an account, their informations were saved in a database. Inside the index js, I would check if the password and all matched (they were encrypted with Passport), then it they do, send the page with a parameter `logged = true`. If they weren't logged in, I would send the page with `logged = false`. Here's an example for logged out:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {title:'randomtitle', logged=false});
});
```

An example for logged in:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
// code checks for cookies. Results shows that user exists. So we send this. we also find the username saved in the variable "someuser"
    res.render('index', {title:'randomtitle', logged=true, username: someuser});
});
```

Then, the handlebars page will check if the user is logged in. For example:

```
<body>
{{if logged}}
    <li> Hello {{username}}! </li>
{{else}}
    <li> LOGIN </li>
{{/if}}
</body>
```

Hopefully, that makes sense. But I think that's a very sketchy approach of doing this! How do professional websites do it? Is there somewhere I can find examples for this?

Also, when I create initialize a server with express for example, it creates 2 routes automatically: index.js and user.js. What is the user.js for?

If anyone knows how it works in general (not specific to Node or Express), also please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of people use passportjs.org for authentication in express. You have a lot of work to do. basically you can save user info from frontend form (html) to the database with get and post requests then add user info to session. This way at your routes you know who is authenticated. You could send the session to the front end template.

you could check to see if the user object is in the session and if it is that means they are logged in.

passportjs helps out with this a lot.

you could do `req.session.logged = true`